# How to count the number of replaces of strings are made?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string "This is a simple text" and I am replacing all its "is" occurrences with "DD". How can I count how many times has that occurrence been found?

```
string str = "This is a simple text";
string occurString = "is";
string replaceString = "DD";

string result = string.Join(replaceString, str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

***P.S: I am not using string.replace() on purpose!***

Comment: What is the purpose of not using `String.Replace()`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the requirement is that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = str.Split(new[] { occurString }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var count = array.Length - 1;
```

Comment: you are basically counting the length of the array there. I want to count the number of occurrences.

Comment: Your surname means Kosovo citizen - Kosovan. I am from Kosovo :)